# doesn't appear to be passing by reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, properties

I've put UIView plotting code into a method as part of my attempt to refactor. It appears the views
(properties) I'm passing into the method are not being affected by whatever the method does (i.e. they're nil). What do I need to change?

Example snippet:

```
{
//...
[self plotLabelTextFieldSlider:_workEffortLabel label:_prewarnLabel textField:_prewarnTextField slider:_prewarnSlider labelText:@"Prewarn:"];
}

- (void)plotLabelTextFieldSlider:(UIView*)anchor label:(UILabel*)label textField:(UITextField*)textField slider:(UISlider*)slider labelText:(NSString*)labelText {

CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(anchor.frame.origin.x,anchor.frame.origin.y + anchor.frame.size.height + margin, anchor.frame.size.width, anchor.frame.size.height);
label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
[self.view addSubview:label];
label.text = labelText;
//...
}
```

In the above example, _prewarnLabel property is still nil when it's referred to elsewhere in the code yet I have set it via the label parameter of the method. Can someone fix my code snippet?

Comment: You are not using any properties in the code you posted. Method parameters are passed by value. Assigning a new value to an object pointer does not change the original pointer.

Comment: Please, please, please learn regular C or Java or some such first, before starting in with Objective-C.  It's not a beginner's language.

Comment: (Objective-C does not pass by reference, BTW, at least not with standard parameters.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are trying to set the variable _prewarnLabel with the line label = [[UILabel alloc] ...  If that is what you want you will need to change your parameter to pass the pointer by reference and not just pass the object by reference.

ie

```
... label:(UILabel**)label ...
```

and then

```
... label:&_prewarnLabel ...
```

I would highly recommend NOT writing your code like this.  It is confusing and hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this, since your method creates a label you need to get back the reference to the new label, would be to do the following:

```
- (UILabel *)plotLabelTextFieldSlider:(UIView*)anchor textField:(UITextField*)textField slider:(UISlider*)slider labelText:(NSString*)labelText {
    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(anchor.frame.origin.x,anchor.frame.origin.y + anchor.frame.size.height + margin, anchor.frame.size.width, anchor.frame.size.height);
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
    label.text = labelText;
    //...

    return label;
}

_prewarnLabel = [self plotLabelTextFieldSlider:_workEffortLabel textField:_prewarnTextField slider:_prewarnSlider labelText:@"Prewarn:"];
```

Update - actually it appears this method might need to create several of the views and pass back several of them. This won't work if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, C, and thus Objective C, passes all parameters by value. It never passes anything by reference. The only way to get that effect is to pass a pointer to a pointer, as in Stephen Johnson's answer. That's what the "(UILabel**)" construct is doing.

When you pass a pointer to a pointer, you can then alter the original pointer, and thus the variable that you are passing in.